# How to merge rows into one based on duplication and conditions in R

Tags: r

my first question in stack-overflow begins.

I have this code:

```
a <- rep(letters[1:4], each = 4); time <- c(0,0,1,1,0,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,0,0,1,2);
cost <- rep(c(0.4,0.2,0.1,0.5,0.5,0.22,0.15,0.18),each =2);
df <- data.frame(a = a, time = time, cost = cost);
```

The code above is just a short illustration from lots of data I have.

The data frame depicted is this one:

[image: Data Frame example]

Do you know how can I merge the rows with duplicated time values into one and also aggregate the costs (they represent different kinds of costs even though they happen to be common in some instances) in each time point for each letter of column a?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% group_by(a, time) %>% summarise(cost = sum(cost))
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'a' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   a [4]
   a      time  cost
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a         0  0.8 
 2 a         1  0.4 
 3 b         0  0.1 
 4 b         1  0.1 
 5 b         2  1   
 6 c         1  1   
 7 c         2  0.44
 8 d         0  0.3 
 9 d         1  0.18
10 d         2  0.18
>
```

Using base R:

```
> aggregate(cost~a+time, df, sum)
   a time cost
1  a    0 0.80
2  b    0 0.10
3  d    0 0.30
4  a    1 0.40
5  b    1 0.10
6  c    1 1.00
7  d    1 0.18
8  b    2 1.00
9  c    2 0.44
10 d    2 0.18
>
```

Comment: That works sure, but what If I have more columns and I would like to add the summarise function output to the original data frame? For example, if my dataframe contains more variables:  a <- rep(letters[1:4], each = 4)

time <- c(0,0,1,1,0,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,0,0,1,2)

cost <- rep(c(0.4,0.2,0.1,0.5,0.5,0.22,0.15,0.18),each =2)

other <-rep(c(0.5,0.4,0.3,0.14),each = 4)

gender <- rep(c('male','female'),each = 8,by = 4)

df <- data.frame(a = a, time = time, cost = cost, other = other, gender = gender)

Comment: you can try: df %>% group_by(a, time, gender) %>% summarise(across(c(cost, other), ~ sum(.)))

Comment: @KarthikS : I seem to have added the exact same suggestions in comments a few minutes back . Your answer is  of course posted much before my comments. The question was offered to me on the SO review queue , so I hadn't seen your answer, sorry for that.

Comment: @R.S. that's ok!

Comment: I think another way, which I think worked for me, is instead of summarize using mutate and then filter the variable for the duplicated values, for example after the mutate: filter(!duplicated(time))

Comment: summarize function, as seen above, removes the duplicates by aggregating continuous column grouped by categorical columns as mentioned in group_by() function. yes, you can do the same by using mutate, which will retain the original number of rows, but I don't see a point why you should be mutating and then filtering instead of just summarizing.